# Suspected remote unknown threat

Tags: security

I am a normal user having only limited knowledge about computer. Someone told me that with the command 'NETSTAT" in the command prompt will tell you who all are connected to your computer. I found the following result which is worrying me.

Can someone tell me what this is?

```
TCP    XXX.XXX.XX.X :53237     allmyworkers:400            SYN_SENT
TCP    XXX.XXX.XX.X :53237     allmyworkers:hosts2-ns      SYN_SENT
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
TCP    XXX.XXX.XX.X :53237     allmyworkers:400            SYN_SENT
TCP    XXX.XXX.XX.X :53237     allmyworkers:hosts2-ns      SYN_SENT
```

This is saying that your computer is attempting to open a TCP connection (SYN_SENT) to a computer called `allmyworkers`.  The first connection is to TCP port 400 on that computer.  The second connection is to TCP port "hosts2-ns".

Beware that a NETSTAT command will only show the connections that are active or being created at the point-in-time you run the command.  Basically you are looking for a needle in a haystack.